# How to fire off an ActionLink (controller method) defined in a view from a modal window in same view. Using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app with a view that has Form, some buttons and modal popups.

My code for the save button works fine. I am not including that code below.

I know I can use the standard Windows confirm but I do not like that ugly confirm.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel Changes", "GetUserProfile", "UserProfile", null, new 
{ onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to continue');"  })
```

So I want to use the nicer looking Bootstrap Modal.

My problem is the cancel button. This button allows the User to cancel their changes and restore it back to it's original state.

When that button is clicked, I prevent the default behavior from happening and I present the Bootstrap modal popup to confirm the cancel of changes.

From the 'yes' selection, I now want to fire off the default behavior which is the controller action method defined in the actionlink for the cancel button. When clicked, the action method gets the data again and returns the entire same view in it's original state before changes were made - hence cancelling the changes.

I don't think I can use an AJAX call in the yes selection to call that action method as that method re-retrieves the data and sends back the entire view.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '@Url.Action("GetUserProfile", "UserProfile")',        
   success: function (response) {
   // - Do a refresh.  
   // - Re-render the view returned which is itself.

   // 1st - remove the entire current view and then replace it with the same view sent back. 
   // But how can I remove the current view as I would be removing the jQuery 
   // code I am executing as it is part of the view?

   $('div [class=zoneRemove']').remove();

   var view = $("<div>").addClass('zoneRemove);

   // Using the 'response'(the view) returned by the controller.
   view.append(response);
 },
 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
   alert('Critical Error: something is wrong in the call to GetUserProfile for canclel changes! Status: ' + xhr.status + '. Error: ' + thrownError.toString() + '. Response Text: ' + xhr.responseText);            }
 });
```

In the "success:" of the AJAX call, I would have to remove the entire current view and then replace it with the same view sent back. But how can I remove the current view as I would be removing the jQuery code I am executing as it is part of the view?

So how else can I process that action method that returns the entire view and re-render the view returned?

---

The view (simplified):

```
@model GbngWebClient.Models.UserProfileForMaintVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessSaveUserProfile", "UserProfile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = 
"multipart/form-data", id = "formId" }))
{
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary saveButton" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel Changes", "GetUserProfile", "UserProfile", null, new { 
@class = "btn btn-info cancelButton" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal13" role="dialog" display="none">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px;">
                <h4 class="text-center">Any unsaved changes will not be processed if you cancel.   
Continue ?</h4>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-yes13">Yes</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-no13">No</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".cancelButton").click(function (e) {
            // Trigger(show) the modal.
            $("#myModal13").modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
            });

            // Prevent the ActionLink from going to the controller.
            e.preventDefault();
        });
           
        $('.btn-yes13').click(function() {
            // Hide the modal.
            $('#myModal13').modal('hide');

            // CONCERN: HOW TO NOW FIRE THE ActionLink TO GO TO THE CONTROLLER METHOD?

            // Return.
            return true;
        });

        $(".btn-no13").click(function () {
            $("#myModal13").modal("hide");

            return false;
        });

        // Remove the modal once it is closed.
        $("#myModal13").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $("#myModal13").remove();
        }); 
    });   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working solution.

I removed the actionlink:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   @Html.ActionLink("Cancel Changes", "GetUserProfile", "UserProfile", null, new { 
   @class = "btn btn-info cancelButton" })
</div>
```

and replaced with:

```
<input class="btn btn-info cancelButton" value="Cancel Changes">
```

To the Yes button of the modal, I added:

```
href="/UserProfile/GetUserProfile"
```

I removed the yes click function.

From the .cancelButton function, I removed:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Here's the final solution:

```
@model GbngWebClient.Models.UserProfileForMaintVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessSaveUserProfile", "UserProfile", FormMethod.Post, new { 
enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "formId" }))
{
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                     <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary saveButton" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input class="btn btn-info cancelButton" value="Cancel Changes">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal13" role="dialog" display="none">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px;">
                <h4 class="text-center">Any unsaved changes will not be processed if you cancel.   Continue ?</h4>
                <div class="text-center">
                    @* Goes to the Controller. No need for AJAX. *@
                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-yes13" href="/UserProfile/GetUserProfile">Yes</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-no13">No</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".cancelButton").click(function (e) {
            // Trigger(show) the modal.
            $("#myModal13").modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false
            });
        });

        $(".btn-no13").click(function () {
            $("#myModal13").modal("hide");

            return false;
        });

        // Remove the modal once it is closed.
        $("#myModal13").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $("#myModal13").remove();
        });
   });
</script>
```